# How to Influence genetics

Tags: workout-routines

How to influence genetics.Can someone from 6pack obtain example 8pack?or 10pack?I care not only about abs but for whole body.Example ,how would be a body trasformation from a thin guy to "normal" look or someone seems normal body to become "advance".I know there are a lot of programs someone can follow with foods but our genetics are playing a role.Can we influence to see more results ?Its not about abs,or transformation the body,its how do we "change our genetics" with physic way.Do we change by our food?by doing extreme activites?what?or we cant do anything?

Comment: It's quite difficult to read your sentences. Do you know someone who could translate for you?

Comment: i hope i was understandable now :)

Comment: There are genes that turn on and off with certain environmental circumstances. I imagine strenuous physical exercise would influence a handful of genes, although I cannot speculate much further than that.

Comment: If you are interested in knowing how genetics can be changed, I'd recommend you to look into epigenetics, which is exactly that, altering gene expression without modification of the gene itself. A good book on it is Inheritance by Sharon Molem.

Answer (score 1):

**There is no way to change your genetic potential.**

If you wish to get bigger and stronger you should eat more (healthier is better, and protein is important) and workout. If you wish to lose weight you should workout and eat less. Its important to determine how many calories you need each day and then either increase or decrease them to reach your goal.

With hard word and proper diet you can reach your genetic potential after 3-4 years of training.

If you aren't satisfied with your genetics then steroids would be an option but I **would not recommend that**.

Comment: how can you sure about there is no way?there are comments that claim and support it may be changing.I will wait for another answer

Comment: I would like to add the word "consistent" to the third paragraph of this answer. People have been getting ripped for hundreds of years through consistently putting the work in. *You cannot change your genetics naturally*